# Copy columns based on the autofiltered column, then paste value only to that autofiltered column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter column B based on values like "Unknown", then filter L column to have un-null values. copy the L column. 
Paste values only to the column B.

```
Before:
ColumnB ..... Column L
1 ..... a
2 ..... b
Unknown.c
3.......d
Unknown.e
Unknown.

After
1 ..... a
2 ..... b
c.......c
3.......d
e.......e
Unknown..
```

```
    Set r1 = Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set r2 = Range("L:L").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set myMultipleRange = Union(r1, r2)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sh1.Range("B:L").AutoFilter
    sh1.Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Unknown", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    sh1.Range("L:L").AutoFilter Field:=11, Operator:=xlFilterValues, Criteria1:="<>"

    LstRw = sh1.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
    If LstRw <> 0 Then
        myMultipleRange.FillLeft
    End If
```

The above code will copy and paste including the format.

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste in a filtered table is no good idea, because it inserts data continously even in hidden rows and messes up your data.

I recommend the following:

- Filter data
- Loop through all visible cells and copy the data row by row

If the following data is given …

[image]

… and you want to replace `unkown` with the data in column L, you can do the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FilterAndCopy()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")

    'Filter data
    ws.Range("B:B").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Unknown", Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim DestinationRange As Range
    On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if filter returns no data rows
    Set DestinationRange = ws.Range("B2", "B" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'find visible cells between B2 (exclude header) and last row in B
    On Error GoTo 0 'always re-activate error reporting!

    If Not DestinationRange Is Nothing Then 'do it only if there is visible data
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In DestinationRange 'copy each value row wise
            Cell.Value = Cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=10).Value 'column L is 10 columns right of B
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution - simply go through each cell in column B and replace "Unknown" with a respective value in column L.

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lngLastRow          As Long
    Dim rngCell             As Range

    With Sheet1
        LastRow = .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Each rngCell In .Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
            If rngCell.Value = "Unknown" Then
                rngCell.Value = .Range("L" & rngCell.Row).Value
            End If
        Next rngCell
    End With
End Sub
```

P.S. Make sure to replace `With Sheet1` statement with a relevant sheet name/code.